# Do you say "Namaste, you", "Namaste, Grandpa", "Namaste, Daddy", "Namaste, Sirs", "Namaste, Boss" or "Namaste, + [proper name]"?

Tags: indian-english, greetings

> [Namaste](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/namaste?q=namaste) (exclamation)
>
> (Indian English) ​a polite greeting said when giving a namaskar (=
>   with the hands placed together as in prayer and the head bent
>   forwards)
>
> ​(also namaskar) [uncountable] a way of greeting somebody in which the
>   hands are placed together as in prayer and the head is bent forwards

---

In English we say, "**Hello Tom**" or "**Goodbye Tom**" but we don't say "**Hello you**" or "**Goodbye you**".

In Indian English, do we say "**Namaste, you**", "**Namaste, Grandpa**", "**Namaste, Daddy**", "**Namaste, Maddam / Sirs**", "**Namaste, Boss**" or "**Namaste, Mary**"?

Comment: I don't think this is an English language question? It's a question about whichever Indian language this word comes from.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Indian English, we say:-

- "Namaste"(you is implied) and not "Namaste,  you".
- "Namaste, Grandpa", "Namaste, Daddy", "Namaste, Maddam / Sirs", "Namaste, Boss" and "Namaste, Mary" are all the right way of saying it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, the "you" is explicit in "Namaste".  The "-te" suffix is a cognate of "thee".

Answer (score 1):

"Namaste" (also "Namaskara" in South India) is often used in reversed order maintaining the order of words. Eg phone call:

> Child: Namaste papa, how are you.
>
> Papa: Namaste beta. I'm fine.

It is used as a standalone conversation starter. Eg (at a shop, when it's your turn):

> You: Namaste.
>
> [Attention received, heads turned]
>
> You: I would like to have ...

Less commonly, when addressing a crowd or formal event.

> Teachers and all my dear friends, Namaskara, my name is ...

PS: Beta |beːʈaː| means child. North Indians use "papa" while people in southern states use 'daddy'.

Answer (score 0):

"Namaste" is generally treated a non-English word.

Some Hindi/English speakers will borrow it into English, and even some mono-lingual English speakers will know the meaning. As an example, in school, an ethnically Indian teacher has started using "namaste" instead of shaking hands. Other teachers and students are happy to respond in the same way. But that doesn't mean that I'll start to say "namaste" with everybody. I will also greet French teachers with "Bonjour", but that is also not an English word.

If you are a Hindi/English speaker, then use "namaste" as you would when speaking Hindi. If you are not a Hindi speaker then use another greeting, such as "Hello".